# How to pause function until value change?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I am trying to pause the execution of the function until the value of the global variable changes. But it doesn't work, after waiting, the function did not continue its work. Where is mistake?

```js
let currentFunction = 1;

const sleep = () => {
    currentFunction += 1;
    console.log(currentFunction);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (currentFunction === 5) {
            return resolve();
        }
        return setTimeout(sleep, 1000);

    });
};

const first = async () => {
    console.log('Hello');
    await sleep();
    console.log('now here');
};

first();
```

Comment: You're only resolving the last promise, not the promise created by the original call to `sleep()`

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks, I assumed it. You have no idea how I can do it correctly?

Comment: Use a loop instead of recursion

Comment: @ThomasSablik Can you show it in an answer? `setTimeout()` doesn't return a promise, so you can't `await` it in a loop.

Comment: You could use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`: https://repl.it/@ShashSinha/CumbersomeDimgreyAutoexec#index.js

Comment: You can write your own "setTimeout" function that returns a promise. https://wandbox.org/permlink/byuHc68q1PoiO3SF